# 403 Error when MVC3 app deployed to SSL enabled server(iis6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, iis-6

I'm kinda lost to this one. i have a perfectly working MVC3 website that is working when deployed to a non-ssl enabled webserver. however, when I moved it to the staging environment where ssl is enabled, i keep getting 403 errors.

I have 0 background on ssl and have no idea on what to look out for. Could anyone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

403 has nothing to do with SSL.  403 means not authorized.  Check your permissions and the authentication settings in IIS.

Is it returning just plain 403 or is there a sub-status like 403.4?

Comment: At first it was 403.4. because i deployed it in a virtual directory under a SSL-enabled parent web site and i had to use https instead of http so i tried to access https://mysite.com that's when i turned up with a plain 403. i actually disabled the authorize attributes to check if it was my just my authentication. Also i have custom errors enabled, shouldn't my custom 403 page be showing instead of the windows default 403?